# Templatized Personalization that is configurable by content authors

Tags: personalization, templates

I have clients who would like to put personalization on components that exist on a multitude of pages, like a side bar on thought leadership or news, to get the most visibility of the personalization.  I know you can personalize content with the standard values on templates to get the desired result.

However, templates are generally developer owned, which results in the clients not being able to change the rules and content for personalization in one spot and affecting the change everywhere.

Has anyone else encountered this issue?  And if so, what was the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We also encountered this issue and solved it by creating an extra layer of templates - might not be the best solution but it works. So what we did:

- create an extra template on top of the one you normally create as developer
- keep these templates in a separate folder (structure) for convenience
- pages are create based on these templates
- these templates cannot have any fields or anything a developer would change - just one base template that is the original template
- these templates do not get overwritten during deploys as they become editor owned instead of developer owned
- create standard values on those templates and explain you editors how to edit those (make sure your standard value items actually work in the experience editor)
- give your editors access to the folder where you created their templates

You can choose to do this for each page template where the editors want to set things (could be personalization) on the standard values or for all (more consequent).

Not sure this is the best solution as you need to give editors rights to a folder with templates but with the correct training it works.

Comment: Unique way of solving the issue. Thank you!